# C# MySqlException: Table doesn't exist - Database name listed twice

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am encountering a problem when attempting to return simple data from a MySQL database I am accessing via a C# application.

Here is the code causing the issue and the error it produces in Visual Studio:

```
using (U04BWFEntities db = new U04BWFEntities())
{
    city theCity = new city();
    customer userQuery = db.customers.First();
    tbox_DebugDB.Text = userQuery.ToString();
}
```

And the error as follows:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
> HResult=0x8013193C
> Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
> Source=EntityFramework

> Inner Exception 1:
> MySqlException: **Table 'U04BWF.U04BWF.customer' doesn't exist**

The U04BWF piece, being the database name, appears to show up twice when it is executing this query and thus the error is accurate -- U04BWF.U04BWF.customer does not exist, but U04BWF.customer does.

**My Real Problem:**  I do not know why the code is trying to run the query like this.  I cannot track down where it is deciding to run the query against U04BWF.U04BWF.customer as opposed to what it *should* be (U04BWF.customer).

As you can see from the code, I am utilizing Entity Framework and, from what I can tell, it created the entities correctly, but I am very new to EF and may simply not know a problem when I see one.

I can switch the connection to ADO and successfully perform queries using non-EF methods.

Mostly I am seeking guidance on how to track this issue down.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Paste the text of the code, and use the code button in the toolbar to get syntax highlighting. Then paste the error message as separate block, and tell us which caused it.

Comment: The code is kind of irrelevant here.  Hence why I didn't share it...

Comment: You should still remove the image and paste the code and exception into separate blocks. Lots of people who might help you won't be able to see that image.

Comment: OK cool - I believe I have updated it with your suggestions here.  Any other ideas are welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: Much better, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.22: [bug 101236](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101236).

As a workaround, you can downgrade to 8.0.21. Oracle claims it will be fixed in the next release, 8.0.24.

Comment: Thank you!  This is the answer I needed.  Additionally, the guidance on downgrading to 8.0.21 did the trick - I am now successfully able to manipulate my MySql database using EF methods such as the one in the original example.  Thanks again.